# Learning C# How does ref and out allow this to work in this specific instance?

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, ref, out

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double weight;
        string num;

        num = getWeight(out weight);
        Console.WriteLine(num + " lb = " + lbToKg(weight) + "kg");
        kgToLb(ref weight);
        Console.WriteLine(num + " kg = " + weight + "lb");

    }

    static string getWeight (out double theWeight)
    {
        theWeight = 10;
        return "Ten";
    }

    static double lbToKg(double pounds = 2)
    {
        return (pounds * 0.45359237);
    }

    static void kgToLb (ref double weight)
    {
        weight = (weight / 0.45359237);
    }

}
```

So I guess my question is, at what point does 'theWeight' become 'weight' and what allows this to happen? is it the output (out) listed in the getWeight() method? if so how? and how does the ref argument effect this?

I feel like i am a so close to getting this, and I just wanted to be perfectly clear on exactly how and why this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may appear that they are doing the same thing but there is quite an important difference in what is happening. Both of these pass the parameter via reference but their use cases are different as well as some different rules.

> 'theWeight' become 'weight'

Because these are passed by reference in both cases, `theWeight` and `weight` both reference the same value.

When you use the `ref` command, the variable that you pass in has to be initialised prior to the call. This does not need to be the case when using `out`.

But then on the other hand, when using `out`, in the method, the parameter marked with it has to be assigned to before the method is done.

There are some more differences but the main point to take away is that both pass a variable by reference.

Comment: So does this mean that out and ref are linked in some way in this context?

Comment: @AndyStav No, they aren't linked. They are similar. Think that `ref` allows you to assign a new value but `out` forces you to do so

Answer (score 1):

`ref` and `out` are pretty the same in this context. The difference is that with `ref` the object has to be initialized before entering the function, while with `out` the object will be initialized inside the function. Since your objects are `double` then no initialization is needed and the two keywords work pretty the same. The only difference is that with `out` you **have to** assign a value while with `ref` it is optional.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    double weight;
    string num;

    num = getWeight(out weight);
        // here weight goes to the function and comes back with value of 10.
    Console.WriteLine(num + " lb = " + lbToKg(weight) + "kg");
    kgToLb(ref weight);
        // here again weight goes to the function and comes back with a new value
    Console.WriteLine(num + " kg = " + weight + "lb");

}
```

so actually `theWeight` is a local variable that holds the reference of `weight` inside the function `getWeight`. Same is weight inside the function `kgToLb`.
Hope this is clear.

you can read more here
https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/csharp/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters